# .NET alpha blend appears as solid colour

Tags: .net, winforms

I created a form that overlays on top of another form in an alpha blended state. This works great on my laptop but I just transferred the program to a computer at work and the form is a solid colour. This is probably a completely obvious question but are there graphics card requirements or colour depth requirements for alpha blending, I had a look and it looks like the colour depth is already 32 bit. My laptop is running windows vista and the work computers are xp incase that makes a difference.

**Edit**: Sorry should have put this is a winforms project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem alpha blending was working for the standard controls however there was a direct show component on the form which doesn't play nice with transparency in XP but does in Vista.

Answer (score 2):

Taking a guess that your application is a WPF one...

Alpha blending of WPF applications is not supported on XP.

Comment: Just edited my post it's a winforms project although if the answer is the same it would be good to know.

Comment: Well I just created a new WinForm app, set Opacity to 50% and ran it, and my WinForm was alpha blended correctly, on a Win XP machine, so it might be something else....

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely this has anything to do with the graphics card/controller, since this is not something too heavy on computational power. It's more likely this has to do with the browser compatibility with alpha blending.

The answer could lie in that you have different browsers on your laptop and work computer.

Comment: Why do you think this is a web browser related question?